# OSGI HttpService couldn't be initialized / injected properly

Tags: java, servlets, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I'd like to use declarative service feature in my OSGI project for my servlets. In details: user is able to install module manually on the main application selecting some *.jar file, main application has embedded OSGI server and when the OSGI module is activated it should be registered for some requests
For example in this way:

```
protected void startup() {
  MyServlet servlet = new MyServlet();
  if (httpService != null)  {
    httpService.registerServlet("/req", servlet, null, null); **//OK!**
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't have httpService instance initialized and that's the problem. Here's the problem servlet module code listing:

```
@Component(name="app", immediate=true)
@Service(value=App.class)
public class App {                
        @Reference(name = "httpService", referenceInterface = HttpService.class, bind = "bindHttpService", unbind = "unbindHttpService")
        private HttpService httpService;

        @Activate
        protected void startup() {                    
            MyServlet servlet = new MyServlet();
            if (httpService != null)    {
                httpService.registerServlet("/req", servlet, null, null);
                //OK!
            } else {
                //Not OK! 
            }
        }

        protected void bindHttpService(HttpService httpService) {               
            this.httpService = httpService;
        }

        protected void unbindHttpService(HttpService httpService) {         
            this.httpService = null;
        }
        // some more code.........              
}
```

Maven bundle plugin settings pom.xml code

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>app</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Embed-Dependency>!org.osgi.core</Embed-Dependency>
            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>                                               
            <Import-Package>                        
             <![CDATA[ 
               org.osgi*,
               com.mynamespace                        
            ]]>                     
            </Import-Package>                       
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And here is simplified code for embedded OSGI server on main application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, "onFirstInit");
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA, "javax.microedition.io");
    Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);
    framework.start();
    BundleContext context = framework.getBundleContext();
    List<Bundle> installedBundles = new LinkedList<Bundle>();
    // install prerequisites
    installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337.jar"));
    installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.4.0.v20131120-1328.jar"));
    installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.200.v20131126-2331.jar"));
    //install servlet module
    installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\app.jar"));
    for (Bundle bundle : installedBundles) {
        bundle.start();
    }
}
```

I was inspired by example from Peter Fries blog (http://www.peterfriese.de/osgi-servlets-flexibility-by-simplicity/), but I can't have httpService instance initialized.
The App module even could be started only if @Reference annotation is removed or covered with comment, in other case module will not be activated.

I suspect that my embedded OSGI doesn't have some required module but can't get the details about it - log console doens't say anything.

### UPDATE

Thanks for the hint Balasz!
There are my mistakes:
0. When `<Embed-Dependency>!org.osgi.core</Embed-Dependency>` is declared httpService can't be automatically binded through @Reference annotatoin, so `bind = "bindHttpService", unbind = "unbindHttpService"` is useless. I removed `<Embed-Dependency>` declaration and it helps to bind httpService like I want to have it (via bindHttpService).

1. Before installing bundles on OSGI server jetty settings should be specified:

   > System.setProperty("jetty.port","8080");
   >   System.setProperty("jetty.home.bundle", "org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot");
2. There are too many jars must be installed on embedded OSGI server, in my case

   // Mandatory bundles            installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337.jar"));        installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.200.v20131126-2331.jar"));
   installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.4.0.v20131120-1328.jar"));
   installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar"));

   ```
           // Container bundles
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.12.v20130726.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.12.v20130726.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_8.1.12.v20130726.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.12.v20130726.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.12.v20130726.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.12.v20130726.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.12.v20130726.jar"));

           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.400.v20130418-1354.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.200.v20131021-1843.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.equinox.http.servletbridge_1.0.300.v20130327-1442.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge_1.3.0.v20130927-1541.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402-1505.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.400.v20130717-1325.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.1.300.v20130402-1529.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\org.osgi.service.obr-1.0.2.jar"));

           // Service bundles
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\jetty-httpservice-8.0.4.v20111024.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\ow2-httpservice-1.2-spec-1.0.0.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\jetty-osgi-boot-8.0.4.v20111024.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\jetty-deploy-8.0.4.v20111024.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\jetty-webapp-8.0.4.v20111024.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\jetty-security-8.0.4.v20111024.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\jetty-http-8.0.4.v20111024.jar"));
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\jetty-xml-8.0.4.v20111024.jar"));

           // Finally, required OSGI bundle
           installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:///MY_PATH\\app.jar"));
   ```

So with these changes I have an initialized httpService object, and now I want to register my servlet instance

```
@Activate
protected void startup() {                    
   MyServlet servlet = new MyServlet();
   if (httpService != null) {
        System.out.println("Greetings! I just want to be sure that service isn't null!")
        //httpService.registerServlet("/req", servlet, null, null); // BAD PLACE
   } else {
        System.out.println("Something goes wrong")
   }
}
```

The code snippet above will show the 'Greetings' message but if I try to register servlet and uncomment 'BAD PLACE' the mesage won't be shown, nothing is happening. Exception is also couldn't be catched; looks like the 'startup' method is ignored. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: The bundles you collected seems to be a bit strange to me. You get bundles from Jetty version 8.0.4 and also from Jetty version 8.1.12. You also get some bundles from equinox. Is it possible that you have the org.osgi.service.http package twice in your OSGi container? In that case it might happen that that your Bundle wires to one of them while the HttpService object is instantiated based on the other. I recommend that you should check the dependencies transitively on the link I sent as that works for sure (with Jetty 9.1.0).

Comment: Thanks @BalazsZsoldos  
There are really a lot of unnecessary bundles to install, so I've modified my sample [my answer below]. 
With your sample you are using Jetty 9.1.0 which depends on javax.servlet 3.1.0 version. unfortunately, org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.400.v20130418-1354 bundle has a constraint: javax.servlet; version="[2.3.0,3.1.0)"' and this bundle is a constraint for org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.httpservice_9.1.0.v20131115 with HttpService implementation. That's why I have to use javax.servlet 3.0.1 version and Jetty 8.0.4 - this set of dependencies doesn't have any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see that you add any bundle that contains any servlet container (jetty or tomcat). I also do not see a bundle in your list that contains a HttpService implementation.

If you need a working example, see the dependencies [here](https://github.com/everit-org/resource/blob/e584714224363efc4c6b85e46d626f039199f721/tests/pom.xml#L171) under the "Jetty with HTTP service" section. If you import those dependencies with their dependencies transitively, you will have a Jetty server with HttpService. In the example the dependencies are commented out as they are only used at development time. Please note that you must start the embedded servlet container in the way that the following system properties are defined:

```
jetty.port=8080
jetty.home.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot
```

If you google, you can find other bundle sets for Tomcat or Jetty.

Comment: Thanks Balasz, now I can have a httpService initialized. However servlet registration doesn't work. I updated my post with last changes

Answer (score 0):

So, the list of installed bundles is the following

```
// without these bundles http service won't be initialized
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.200.v20131126-2331.jar");          
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.4.0.v20131120-1328.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.400.v20130418-1354.jar");

context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar");                                
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-httpservice-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-server-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-osgi-boot-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-deploy-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-continuation-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-servlet-8.0.4.v20111024.jar"));
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-webapp-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-server-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-security-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-http-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-io-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-util-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
context.installBundle(libsDirectoryURL + "jetty-xml-8.0.4.v20111024.jar");
```

I'd like to use javax.servlet 3.1.0 with jetty 9.1.0 but couldn't solve the problem with jetty-httpservice which depends on org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet (perhaps there is some version of this jar which works fine with javax.servlet 3.1.0 but I didn't find it)

I've posted a little code sample of the embedded OSGI server with HttpService on bitbucket, maybe someone find it usefull:
https://bitbucket.org/vbashur/diff/src/

Comment: **NOTE** running the code under eclipse IDE with Java 6 doesn't take an effect for OSGI service, so make sure that build path is configured for jdk1.7